# Dynamically set all properties files at runtime:

Tags: java, spring, properties, properties-file

I am trying to dynamically set all properties at run-time in a java spring application. I am successfully doing that with program arguments/System Properties ([a different SO post explaining this in detail here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50420048/spring-system-property-resolver-customization)), but I haven't figured out a way to dynamically read all properties in `.properties` files and edit their values. The property sources stored under the spring application context do not contain properties in the previously mentioned files.

Is it possible to load up a spring app and before creating any beans, step in and edit the values across all properties files being loaded in the project?

Comment: Properties is read onloy and just tell to the application what is configured. If you want to change the values by adding some information just encapsulate under a @ Configuration class, inject your properties with @ Value annotation and use getters to access new properties with transformed info.

Comment: Property files are expected to be a static read-only input for your application. The values that you are trying to edit - are these really config?

Comment: The values are read only, but should be resolved... So technically they are a middle value in a process. A good example would be database passwords. You shouldn't store this in plain text, so you would likely want to resolve the value on startup.

Comment: @ChadVanDeHey for a use-case like you mentioned, the values would need to be either passed as command line arguments while starting the app, or should be used via a config server like I mentioned in my answer. The values in properties file are static and cannot be resolved to a different value at runtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The properties added to the properties file are read when the app starts. Once it is up and running, changes to the properties file wouldn't reflect unless you restart the app. There is no way to dynamically update the properties file to reflect in the app.

The only way to dynamically update properties of an app would be to use something like a configuration server. Read about it here.

https://spring.io/guides/gs/centralized-configuration/